# Play sound with ActionScript3 on iOS cause undesired effects

Tags: ios, apache-flex, audio, mobile, air

I'm using Adobe AIR with ActionScript3 to play a sound recorded from the microphone on iOS device.
I store the microphone samples (which are mono) in a file using FileStream.writeFloat method.
I later create a Sound object and register to SampleEvent, in the SampleEvent I read the file stored earlier with the mic samples and write them twice (because the output is stereo).

The problem is that when I run it in AIR simulator it works great and replay the sound great and when I play it on iOS device (iPad) the sound runs twice as fast.

```
    private function onSampleData(event : SampleDataEvent):void
    {

        // the following lines of code are modifying the sound object and creates a "pitch" effect
        var sample:Number;

        var outputLength:int = 0;
        while (outputLength < 2048) {
            // until we have filled up enough output buffer
            if (_micSamplesStream.bytesAvailable < 4)
            {
                break;
            }

            // read out the left and right channels at this position
            sample = _micSamplesStream.readFloat();

            // write the samples to our output buffer
            event.data.writeFloat(sample);
            event.data.writeFloat(sample);

            outputLength++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've built the application as ad-hoc package and install it on iPad using TestFlight and now everything seem to work just fine.

I guess during debug Adobe AIR did not manage to fill the sound buffer fast enough and cause the distortion.